# How to delete several lines in txt with conditional

Tags: python

everyone! I have  just started  learning python
I have a problem with some txt file
I want to delete all data with KMAG less than 5.5
but I have no idea any suggestions?
code  below just what I could

```
file = open("experiment.txt", "r")
for line in file:
if 'KMAG' in line:
    print(line)
file.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHinH.png)

Comment: It seems like it is some evenly key separated file. You need to check if it something like a tsv(Tab seperated values) file. It would be much easier to perform manipulation on such file.

Comment: Can you update your post to have a link to the file or just a piece of it, no one knows how it is structured inside!!

Comment: Is this a standard file format and is there an existing python module that knows how to convert the text into python objects?

Comment: Please paste the data directly into the question. We don't want a link that goes stale over time and it would be nice to copy/paste for our own experiments.

Comment: thank you, Vshnudev, I have a Q.  If it is tsv i can i use pandas to solve the task?

Comment: Sorry guys for such an unclear question,  every data goes through 2 empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things. First, it appears that this file has multiline records delimited by a line with a single decimal number. Use that to read the file a record at a time:

```
import re
from decimal import Decimal

def get_records(fileobj):
    record = []
    for line in fileobj:
        if re.match(r"\s*\d+\s*$", line):
            # got new record, emit old
            if record:
                yield record
            record = [line]
        else:
            record.append(line)
    if record:
        yield record
    return
```

Now you can peek into each record to see if its data you want to keep. I'm using the `decimal` module because because the python binary `float` does not exactly represent decimal floats.

```
min_val = Decimal("5.5")

with open("experiment.txt") as infile, open("foo.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for record in get_records(infile):
        # we got record number\nheader\ndata with kmag\n...
        kmag = re.split(r"\s+", record[2].strip())[-1]
        if Decimal(kmag) >= min_val:
            outfile.writelines(record)
```

Comment: you are genius, thank you tdelaney!  your code works perfectly!